# ¿Como verificar si un programa se esta ejecutando o se ejecuta? Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, aplicación-escritorio

es que quiero hacer un programa como tipo control parental, para los niños y es el hecho de que, al momento de abrir un programa **ej: Roblox** quisiera que se ejecutara el python pidiendole resolver unas operaciones matematicas y si es correcto pues lo deje jugar normal, pero si no lo es, cierre el programa, entonces quisiera saber como podria hacer eso

O otra alternativa que tengo es, una extension que al momento de entrar a la pagina de roblox ejecute una ventana con las operaciones, pero prioriso lo de python.

espero respuestas y muchas gracias a todos :D

Comment: En cuanto a la extensión deberás hacerlo si o si con JavaScript ya que es el único lenguaje que soportan las extensiones. En cuanto al programa que quieres pues si es posible pero... ¿que has intentado? Aquí nadie te dará el código

Comment: Si los usuarios no son capaces de averiguar donde está el ejecutable de Roblox, puedes hacer que, en lugar de haber un exe directo a Robox, accesos directos a un programa que reciba de argumento el programa a ejecutar y lo ejecute luego de que el usuario realice los cálculos matemáticos.

Comment: @DanteS. sería buena opción, pero digamos que el usuario instala este programa luego de  que fuera instalado Roblox, en ese caso se debería de reemplazar el acceso directo (y de los otros programas que considere para el control parental)

Comment: @christian Exactamente. Es la mejor manera que se me ocurre, pero no creo que haya una mejor forma.

Comment: @DanteS. el módulo `psutil` da la posibilidad de conocer que procesos se están ejecutando, por lo que puede servir de algo. Se podría tener un script corriendo en segundo plano verificando siempre los programas ejecutados, si en algún momento se abre Roblox entonces se mata al proceso y se muestra el problema matemático a resolver. Es lo que se me ocurre a mi, pero no sé que tan práctico sea.

Comment: @Christian tu punto tiene dos problemas. Primero, matar el proceso puede romper el programa que se estaba ejecutando. Segundo, como diferenciaría tu programa el proceso abierto por el mismo y el proceso abierto por el usuario?

Comment: @DanteS. en cuanto al primer problema, no se me ocurre solución alguna y tampoco sabía que podía romperse >_<. Para el segundo punto creo que se puede usar un flag para que ignore al programa cuando el problema matemático sea resuelto.

Comment: @Christian ya he adelantado mucho en el programa de las operaciones, es algo simple ya que apenas estoy aprendiendo, aqui estaria el [video](https://youtu.be/c0I6KNmXbO8) y me han dicho que con python puedo bloquear archivos entonces mi idea es algo tipo bloquear el roblox para que no lo puedan ejecutar

Comment: @DanteS. eso tenia pensado, remplazar el acceso directo del roblox por el mio, la cosa es que para entrar a un juego en roblox es desde la pagina de roblox, desde ahi el navegador manda una orden que hace que el roblox se abra y lo conecte al dicho servidor del juego

Comment: Entonces hay muchas posibilidades en hacer que python bloquee el juego, y ahsta tengo pensado hacerlo de forma universal es decir que seleccionen el juego que quieran bloquear y asi no podrian jugarlo, la otra seria ocultarlo pero da igual con roblox